# Deployed autonumber field not populated

Tags: apex, account, auto-number

I needed an autonumber field in account for an apex class which sends mails to customers. In sandbox I added an autonumber field and checked the option to generate values for existing records/accounts.

After deploying to production no values were generated for existing accounts.
Autonumber field is readonly, so it seems I cannot use a script to update it. 
Since the field is related to my Apex class, it cannot be deleted (and added again) or changed to another type (and changed back to autonumber with option to generate values).

Is there any chance to get my autonumber values?

Comment: Change it to a text field, data load the values you want, then change it back to auto number.

Comment: cannot change field type since it's related to my apex class.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should open a case with support.

Comment: And also, probably would have been better to create that field in prod and check that option than trying to deploy it. Lessons learned. Still, support should be able to help you fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These steps should work

1. comment out the code which refers to the autonumber field
2. change the field type of the autonumber field to text. If this is displayed on a screen, you'll notice the field is now editable.
3. using data loader, load the data you need into the field
4. change the field type back to autonumber - remember to set the starting number to the next value or else it will start the new records from 1

related articles which helped were - [How do I reset/restart an auto number field?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005195&language=en_US)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Anil's answer, there's a way to do this as part of the deploy so you can avoid the Data Loader and fieldtype swap.

- You will need to manually edit your source file for the object in question (e.g. `Foo__c`)
- You will need to add in two lines as shown below for the autonumber field you desire to deploy and generate values for existing records.

  ```
  <fields>
    <fullName>Foo_Number__c</fullName>
    <description>bar</description>
    <displayFormat>{000000000}</displayFormat>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Foo Number</label>
    <populateExistingRows>true</populateExistingRows>  // add this line
    <startingNumber>1</startingNumber>  // add this line with desired startVal
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>AutoNumber</type>
  </fields>
  ```

  - Don't forget to deploy `xxx.profile` files to make the field visible to those profiles that care.
  - Deploy with your IDE (or ant, sfdx, Gearset or equivalent)

When you deploy to the target org, SFDC will set the starting number to the value of `<startingNumber>` and will launch the populate existing records background job.

The reason this works is that tools that use the Metadata API (as of V42) [don't have the ability to fetch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm?search_text=customfield) either of the `populateExistingRecords` or `startingNumber` attributes of the `CustomField` metadata object. But they can deploy those values.

> You can’t retrieve the starting number of an auto-number field through
>   Metadata API. To specify a Starting Number while deploying, add a
>   startingNumber tag for your field to your package.xml file. For
>   example: 42

Answer (score -1):

Source 
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008l9ZIAQ
Try anonymous APEX code to populate existing records.

If this does not work you need to deploy after commenting your field use in apex. Then change field populate it. Deploy back

Comment: It's a read-only field...